# Return New Array Without Specified Element In Original, one-liner?

Tags: jquery, arrays

I did some research but couldn't find anything exactly matching my use case.

I need to quickly return a new array without an element in the original one. In other words, I need to somehow combine `splice / indexOf /` etc., but the below is failing: it's only returning the one element "TEST" that I'm removing.

The function below needs to return a new array with everything except the removed item.

```js
function newArrayWithout(array, elem) {
   return array.splice(array.indexOf(elem), 1);
}

var array = ["abc", "def", "TEST", "ghi"];

var newarray = newArrayWithout(array, "TEST");

console.log('New array: ' + newarray);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if solve your question:

```
var myarr = ["abc", "def", "TEST", "ghi"];

var r = myarr.filter(function(el){
   return el != "TEST"; 
});

alert(r);
console.log(r);
```

[JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/FBlade/uwn4kgoc/)

Answer (score 0):

Using [`.splice()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp) and [`.indexOf()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp), you can do what you already have. But what you need to return is the array because the return value of `.splice()` is the element that is removed. Not the remaining elements. If you want to preserve the original array, you need to copy the array first. For example

```js
var array = ["abc", "def", "TEST", "ghi"];

// Copy the values of array first
var newArray = array.slice();

// Splice using indexOf the element to be removed
newArray.splice(newArray.indexOf("TEST"), 1);

console.log('original :' + array);
console.log('new :' + newArray);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```